# How can I create more than 100 YouTube channels from a single Google account?

Tags: youtube

Create 100+ youtube channels from my account?

I would like to upload videos in multiple languages, with each language in it's own channel.

Youtube says there is a limit of 100 channels per Google account. Is it possible to increase this limit?
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3046356

Any idea who to ask?
(YouTube's "Ask the Help community" is currently disabled)
https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/204228039/posting-in-this-forum-has-been-disabled?hl=en-GB

Thanks, Graham